# Problem with a mv script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, mv

I am having a problem with a `mv` script.

1. I create a `Test` folder:

   ```
   mkdir Test
   ```
2. In this folder I create subfolders:

   ```
   mkdir -p Pics20{18..23}/{01..12}
   ```
3. In the `Test` folder I create many files:

   ```
   touch IMG20{18..23}{01..12}{01..30}{01..10}.jpg
   ```
4. Now I need to move all these IMG files to the respective subfolders, so I wrote a script:

   ```
   for i in 20{18..23}
   do
     for j in {01..12}
     do
       mv IMG20$i$J* Pics20$i/$j
     done
   done
   ```

   But I keep getting an error:

   ```
   cannot stat 'IMG202018j*': No such file or directory
   ```

What is wrong with my script?

Comment: 1. Uppercase J is undefined, use lowercase j; 2. It is recommended to enclose references to variables in double quotes. - Please try something like `"IMG20$i$j"*` etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not help. I keep getting the same message, no such file or directory ((

Comment: Your `i` has a `20` in it, as does `IMG20$i`, so that's `IMG202018` when `i` is `2018`.

Answer (score 3):

I had to create a test directory with 'your content'. That way I made a working one-liner,

```
for i in 20{18..23}; do for j in {01..12}; do mv "IMG$i$j"* "Pics$i/$j"; done; done
```

You had to replace J by j and add semicolons to separate statements. It was also important to get the file names and directory names to match (watch how to add '20')

It is also good practice to double-quote expressions with variables.

Comment: Yes, thank you for this. However, the program works only for one cycle, for one year 2018. It does not work for 2019, 2020, etc. Should there be another for, for the year?

Comment: My one-liner works for me for all the years 2018 ..2023 that you specified in the original test example. Please specify exactly what input data that cannot be managed. Please notice that I run it in `bash`.

Comment: Hey @sudodus, I think I got my error, I probably launched the script from the false path. I have ran the script again and it worked flawlessly! Thank you very much, again!

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you solve your problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a well-organized file structure, a simple `rename` will do. If the number of objects may exceed ARG_MAX, reading from `stdin` is preferable.

```
printf %s\\0 IMG*.jpg | \
   rename -0 -d 's|IMG(....)(..)(.*)|Pics$1/$2/$3|'
```